# gitignore globbing or RE?

Tags: git, version-control, project-management, gitignore

I have a little trouble with some auto generated binary files in my project.

So, I have 2 questions:

1)Does gitignore ( the file from a git repository which says which files should not be tracked) uses globbing or regular expressions ?

2)FOr files that are included in gitignore, but are already tracked, do they become untracked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitignore` uses globs. [This page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) should give you all the details.

Also, to ignore uncommitted changes in a file that is already tracked, use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.